# tkinter os.path.isfile, os.path.exists doesn't work and freeze the app

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, os.path

I just made a little program to make some plots with tkinter in python.
And I'm trying to make the app to create png file not overlapping the previous one.
So like, if it exists, rename it as ~ (1).png kinda thing.

But when I run `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.exists`, the app just freezes. Like, endless hourglasses turning and saying not responding, you know.

So, this is the function I binded with the button.

```
def get_information_S():
    global nation_list, checked_list, output, year_menu, auto_flag, df
    year = year_menu.get()
    checked_list.sort()
    nations = []
    if auto_flag == 0:
        for n in range(len(nation_list)):
            nations.append(nation_list[n][0].get())
        
    else:
        pass
        
    if len(year) == 0:
        output_log("연도를 선택해주세요.\n")
    elif len(checked_list) == 0:
        output_log("hs코드를 선택해주세요.\n")
    else:
        output_log("\n\n분석 연도 : "+str(year)+"\n분석 품목 : "+str(checked_list)+"\n분석 국가 : "+str(nations)+"\n분석을 실시했습니다.\n")

        for x in range(len(checked_list)):
            os.makedirs("result", exist_ok=True)
            os.makedirs("result\\single", exist_ok=True)
            os.makedirs("result\\single\\hs_"+str(checked_list[x]),exist_ok = True)
    
            df_test = df[df.hs6==int(checked_list[x])]
            df_test = df_test[df_test.year==int(year)]
            
            file_loc = "result\\single\\hs_"+str(checked_list[x])+"\\hs_"+str(checked_list[x])+"_"+str(year)+'.png'

            f = -1
            while True:
                f+= 1
                if os.path.isfile(file_loc) == True:
                    if f == 0:
                        file_loc = file_loc.replace('_.png','_('+str(f)+').png')
                    else:
                        file_loc = file_loc.replace('('+str(f-1)+')','('+str(f)+')')
                    continue
                else:
                    break
                    
                    
            plain_graph(df_test, file_loc, checked_list[x], nations)
```

Well, it's my first time dealing with GUI.
Is there a way I can use os.path.isfile or os.path.exists? Or any walkaround?
Thank you!

Comment: What the purpose of the while loop? I think it is not necessary.

Comment: @acw1668 Oh I thought it can handle to keep previous files alive. I want to save files as (1), (2), (3). So hoping to check it with while. But while isn't problem since I tested `print(os.file.isfile(file_loc))` before while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value of `file_loc` is something like `"result\\single\\hs_xxxx_2021.png"` (assume `year` is 2021), then in the first iteration of the while loop, `if f == 0` will be evaluated as `True` and so

```
file_loc = file_loc.replace('_.png','_('+str(f)+').png')
```

will be executed, but nothing will be replaced as `_.png` is not found in `file_loc` and so `file_loc` is kept as initial value and `continue` line will proceed to next iteration.  As the `file_loc` does not change and `f` is increased, the else part

```
file_loc = file_loc.replace('('+str(f-1)+')','('+str(f)+')')
```

will be executed but again nothing is replaced as the search pattern is not found in `file_loc`.

Then same result happens for every iteration followed and make the while loop an infinite loop.

So the mentioned line should be changed to:

```
file_loc = file_loc.replace('.png','('+str(f)+').png')
```

Comment: Ohhh I was so fool that I changed _.png to .png in one part and didn't in other part. That's why it kept looping. I thought it will eventually break afterall, but yeah (ironically) there is a loophole to keeping it in loop.

Totally out of my head. I'll try this one when I got to home.
Thanks for the generous and detail explanation!